# insert element into db only if it doesnt exist

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hy i am using mongoose.

I have this query that inserts about 30 elements into my database:

```
await Code.insertMany(information);
```

Information looks like:

```
[
  {
    discount: 20,
    url: '...',
    code: "...",
    sponsorUrl: "...",
    sponsorAccount: "..."
  },
]
```

The `url` is unique. I want to add again 30 items into the database but it could be that 10 items from 30 are already saved in the database

How can i achieve that? I could loop it but is there an better solution?

I dont want to have duplicated urls

Answer (score 1):

The upsert = true option creates the object if the url does not already exist in a document in the collection.

```js
for (var i of information){
    Code.update(
        {'url' : i.url }, 
        {$set : i}, 
        {upsert : true, multi : true}, 
        function(err, doc){
                if(err) throw err;
                console.log(doc);
        }
    )
}
```